# Get Total of files changed, additions and deletions of a SVN commit

Tags: svn

I tried to get the total of files changed, total of lines added and removed in a specific SVN commit, without success.

I tried something like:

```
svn diff -r 12983:12984 > patch.diff 
cat patch.diff | grep $'+'
cat patch.diff | grep $'-'
```

But it doesn't look right. Also, I can't figure out how many files I have changed.

How can I do that?

---

I actually get it working with the following:

```
svn diff -r REV1:REV2 > patch.diff 
cat patch.diff | grep $'^+ ' | wc -l # additions
cat patch.diff | grep $'^- ' | wc -l # deletions
svn diff --summarize -r REV1:REV2 | wc -l # total files changed
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: `svn log -v` is probably helpful here.

Comment: not really. It only shows the changed paths and how much lines the commit message have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use something like 
`svn diff --summarize -r REV1:REV2 <PATH/URL> | wc -l`

Hope this helps.

Regards

Comment: Yes, it gaves me the number of changed files... Do you know how to get the lines changed/added/removed? My version didn't seems to work very well...

Comment: The changes that were made can be obtained by using -c option :svn diff -c Rev <path/URL>..Also edited my last ans, had forgot to include the path/URL:)

Answer (score 1):

Looks about right to me, but I'd grep for '+ ' not just '+' as you will get lines like:

```
+++ xyz.txt <revision n>
```

at the beginning of every file in your unified diff.

You might like to read the [format of patch files](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Detailed-Unified.html#Detailed-Unified).

Comment: @caarlos0 well, you should have said that on your question then! Makes a world of difference ;-)